# PHP Contact form doesn't shows the user an error

Tags: php

So I'm trying to make this PHP Contact form, and if something is left empty or entered with invalid characters I want them to get shown an error.

I've two files: contactform.php and contact.php. contact.php contains the script, contactform.php contains the script to show the errors.

Contactform.php:

```
<html> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<head>

</head>



<div class="container">


    <center class="contacttext"><h3>Contact opnemen</h3></center>



  <form class"contact-form" action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="naam">
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mailadres">
    <input type="text" name="onderwerp" placeholder="Onderwerp">
    <textarea name="bericht" placeholder="bericht"></textarea>
    <input type="Submit" value="verstuur"></input>

<?php
    $fullUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if (strpos($fullUrl, "submit=empty") == true) {
    echo "<center><p class='error'> Je hebt niet alle velden ingevuld!</p></center>";
    exit();
}
elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "submit=char") == true) {
    echo "<center><p class='error'> Je hebt ongeldige karakters gebruikt!</p></center>";
    exit();
    }

elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "submit=email") == true) {
     echo "<center><p class='error'> Je hebt een ongeldig e-mailadres gebruikt!</p></center>";
     exit();
        }

 elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "submit=succes") == true) {
     echo "<center><p class='error'> Heb bericht is succesvol verstuurd!</p></center>";
     exit();   
            }


?>


</form>
</div>



  </body>
  </html>
```

contact.php:

```
<?php   

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
    $mailVan = $_POST['mail'];
    $bericht = $_POST['bericht'];

    $mailNaar = "name@domain.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailVan;
    $txt = "Je hebt een e-mail gekregen van ".$naam.".\n\n".$bericht;


mail($mailNaar, $onderwerp, $txt, $headers);
header("Location: index.php?mailsend");


if (empty($naam) || empty($onderwerp) || empty($mailVan) || empty($bericht)) {
    header("Location: index.html?submit=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    if (!filter_var($mailVan, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: index.html?submit=invalidemail");
        exit();
    } else {

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $naam) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$", $onderwerp)) {
    header("Location: index.html?submit=char");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: index.html?submit=succes");
    exit();
}
}
}
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The <center> tag is not supported in HTML5, so I recommend using CSS instead. To read more: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: In every case in the contactform code, you redirect to another page. This creates a whole new HTTP request, thus you lose any information which was in the current script. In the case of errors you see to redirect to "index.html", and you pass a parameter to that page to indicate the nature of the error. So you could write some script in index.html to read the querystring value and display a message. But it won't be very user-friendly because the user is no longer on the page containing their form, so they have to go back to that page and re-enter the data. Your design is a bit strange.

Comment: The more conventional approach would be to have the form post back to contactform.php, and have a script block which only executes when it detects the form has been submitted (e.g. presence of particular POST values). If everything goes to plan, then you can redirect the user somewhere else, no problem. But if there's a validation error you want to return them to the same form, and show the error - so the code would cause the form to be re-displayed, but with the error message shown, and all the existing values pre-filled (based on the POST data) so the user can see and correct them